# Intent action OPEN_DOCUMENT doesn't always work with FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to use the new [Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html) but there is an intermittent problem happening when persisting the opened files. Here is what I'm doing.

To select the file, I use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.setType("audio/*");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);

startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Then on `onActivityResult()`:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    uri = data.getData();
    final int takeFlags = data.getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION;
    getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags);
    ...
}
```

This seems to work most of the time, i.e., the uri gets persisted and I can open the file even after reboot. However, it's not always the case and not across all devices. I'm getting some users complaining that they can't open the file after rebooting the phone and have to select it again.

I could simulate the problem here when I upgrade the app. Sometimes after upgrading, it seems that the persistence gets lost. But it's again intermittent so it's hard to find out what could be wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have only lightly experimented with the storage access framework so far. I can certainly see scenarios in which a permission grant might be forgotten, such as on uninstall and reinstall of an app. Plus, as the docs note, the `Uri` may no longer be valid (e.g., document was deleted by another app). Are you examining `getPersistedUriPermissions()` at all, to see if you still have rights to this `Uri`?

Comment: Thanks! I understand the cases where the app gets deleted/reinstalled or when the file no longer exists. I use `getPersistedUriPermissions()` to handle these kinds of cases. But I can't find out why the permission is forgotten on app upgrade for example.

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you suggest any alternative to using the storage access framework that works well on API 19?

Comment: Is this happening on Nexus devices or the emulator? If the answer is yes, then this is definitely an issue with stock Android. Also, are there any commonalities in the document provider (e.g., the problem always occurs with such-and-so provider)? "Can you suggest any alternative to using the storage access framework that works well on API 19?" -- well, the stuff that has been used since API Level 1 (e.g., `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`) still works, though it may not have all the features you wish (e.g., persistable `Uri` permissions).

Comment: It happens on a Nexus device. Users have reported it on other devices running 4.4.2 as well. I'm using whatever provider that is available on the phone so I will see if I can detect any pattern. It's probably overkill to develop my own provider for this. I just want to have a persistent read-only access to one or two files per user. Thanks again.

Comment: "I just want to have a persistent read-only access to one or two files per user" -- short of making a copy of the file, you have no means of having guaranteed persistent access to the file prior to `takePersistableUriPermission()` and API Level 19. If you do find a guaranteed reproducible test case for this, and you are seeing it occur on a stock Nexus device or the emulator, definitely [file a bug report](http://b.android.com) with an app that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was the problem? I'm struggling with it right now under Android 10, even have 2 apps: small StorageTest app, which retains the permissions after a reboot, and the big app that I'm trying to convert, which forgets them after a reboot. Can't find where the difference lies...